# Automap multiple databases with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app currently working fine Automapping one database, but I need to access another database now as well. I tried to follow the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation here: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/, but it doesn't seem to work with the automap_base.

The only changes I made were creating `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` and adding the `__bind_key__` in **models.py**. The error I get is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Table2|table2 could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'table2'
```

However, both tables have a primary key column, and if I get rid of `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`, set the URI to that of `db2`, and only have `table2` in **models.py**, everything works fine.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is. It looks like Flask is still looking for `table2` in `db1`. I think my problem is that some change needs to be made to **__init__.py** as well, but I don't know what that would be.

**config.py**

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@host/db1'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'otherDB':        'mysql://user@host/db2',
}
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model = automap_base(db.Model)
from app import models
db.Model.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)
```

**models.py**

```
class Table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'

class Table2(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'otherDB'
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Automap` is a extension of **sqlalchemy** to reflect an existing database into a new model. It has not been baked into `flask-sqlalchemy`. Plz see the issue [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/398). You can connect to multiple databases with `Flask-SQLAlchemy` like this:

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import models  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # show the table schema
    print m3.Table1.__table__.c
    print m3.Table2.__table__.c
```

**models.py**

```
db.reflect() # reflection to get table meta


class Table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'


class Table2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    __bind_key__ = 'otherDB'
```